Cannot redirect to another url in Flask upon submitting a form
I feel this is a basic problem however I'm having trouble getting round it.
I'm trying to have a form on one html page, then when it's submitted it redirects to another html page.
here is my code:
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, StringField


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='my-secret-key'

class SpeedForm(FlaskForm):
    speed=StringField('speed')
    submit=SubmitField('enter')


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form=SpeedForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print('***')
        return redirect('/results')
    return render_template('index.html',form=form)

@app.route('/results',methods=['GET','POST'])
def results():
    return render_template('results.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

and here is the html page
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <form action="/" method="post">
        {{ form.csrf_token() }}
        {{ form.speed.label }} {{ form.speed(size=20) }}
        {{ form.submit() }}
    </form>
</html>

I have installed the necessary extensions - flask-wtf. The initial page loads fine, but when I submit I get a 'method not allowed' and  a POST http 405.
2
I tried to dumb it right down to get the basics, and made an even simpler program, following only the Flask documentation and the examples given there. Here is my main file:
from flask import Flask, request, redirect,url_for

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key='my-secret-key'

@app.route("/")
@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect(url_for('results'))
    return '''
        <form method="post">
            <p><input type=text name=value>
            <p><input type=submit value=enter>
        </form>
    '''

@app.route('/results',methods=['POST','GET'])
def results():
    return '''
        <p>success </p>
    '''

However I'm still getting the 405 method not allowed. At this point I am wondering if the problem lies deeper in my computer, as I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work. By the way I've made a basic Flask program before that didn't have this problem, but I'm getting it now by starting from scratch.
If anyone can spot anything or suggest a reason why it might not be working, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Because you are POSTing to / but your decorator says that POST is only allowed for /submit and /results routes? Try to force <form action="/submit">.

Thank you for your answers. jkrcma's comment is what pointed to the solution to my particular problem. roganjosh's answer is also helpful.
In the end I have simply added methods='POST' argument to the route decorator named('/'). I actually did this with my previous Flask project, so I should have remembered to do it here.
Here is my updated code, in case anyone trips up in the same way:
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, session
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import SubmitField, StringField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY']='my-secret-key'

class SpeedForm(FlaskForm):
    speed=StringField('speed')
    submit=SubmitField('enter')


@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
@app.route('/index',methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form=SpeedForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['speed']=form.speed.data
        return redirect('/results')
    return render_template('index.html',form=form)

@app.route('/results',methods=['GET','POST'])
def results():
    speed=session['speed']
    return render_template('results.html',speed=speed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

